# Running a compiled c program (or .o) in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, c, executable

I have a program written in c that I want to run in an iOS app. The program takes as parameters a path to an image, processes it and outputs another image in a provided location. I have the .o file and the compiled executable. Is it possible to include one of those in the app? If yes, how?

Comment: If the .o was built for the appropriate ARM processors you might be able to link the .o into the final executable. But iOS apps can't normally launch other executables due to sandboxing restrictions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @rmaddy. I guess that the simplest way to make it work is to include the c code in the app project

Answer (score 0):

You have to include a header file with the function declaration and link the .c file. ie, `#include headerfile.h` in the class you need.